# Can't get styl to run (its an NPM package)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I have nodejs, grunt and npm installed, did it months ago was able run things and then I had a project come up so wasn't able to dive into it as much as I wanted, but I know it was all setup correctly. Now months later I need to get "styl"

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/styl**

working. I installed it like the instructions say to
**npm install -g styl**

I'm at the directory I want to be and tried to run

**styl style.style style.css**

and it wont run, it just sits there

I'm on windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that css file is written in SASS-style with nesting, you have to pass *-w* flag to use "[significant whitespace pre-processor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styl#whitespace-significant-syntax)".

As shown in the example, you have to enable the following command: (with the angle brackets)

```
$ styl -w < style.style > style.css
```

Otherwise, it produces empty style.css file.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an error:
C:\Users\Person\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\styl\node_modules\css-whitespace\lib\compiler.js:53

throw new Error('invalid node "' + node[0] + '"');
Error: invalid node "indent"

Comment: Looks like you have wrong code indentation. The stack trace should point out to the exact line where the parser fails. You could also use [stylint](https://github.com/rossPatton/stylint) to catch the errors, so the compiler won't whine anymore :)